# Trouble capturing window with winAPI BitBlt for some applications only

Tags: python, windows, winapi, screenshot, pywin32

I've put together a simple python script that is supposed to take a screenshot of a window whose name contains a specific string. The code I use is the following,

```
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con
import PIL.Image

def getWindowHandle(name):        
    windowList = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(lambda hwnd, wndList:
                             wndList.append((win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd), hwnd)),
                         windowList)

    for pair in windowList:
        if name in pair[0]:
            return pair[1]

    return None


class Window():
    def __init__(self, hwnd = None):
        if not hwnd: return

        l, t, r, b   = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
        sl, st, _, _ = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
        cl, ct       = win32gui.ClientToScreen(hwnd, (l, t))

        self.size     = (r - l, b - t)
        self.position = (cl - sl, ct - st)

        hDC   = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
        self.windowDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hDC)
        self.newDC = self.windowDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

        #win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC)

        self.bitmap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        self.bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(self.windowDC, self.size[0], self.size[1])
        self.newDC.SelectObject(self.bitmap)

    def __del__(self):
        self.newDC.DeleteDC()
        self.windowDC.DeleteDC()
        del self.bitmap

    def screenshot(self, location = 'C:\\Users\\Grieverheart\\Desktop\\'):
        self.newDC.BitBlt((0, 0), self.size, self.windowDC, self.position, win32con.SRCCOPY)
        self.bitmap.Paint(self.newDC)

        bmpinfo = self.bitmap.GetInfo()
        bmpstr  = self.bitmap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        im = PIL.Image.frombuffer('RGB', self.size, bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)
        try:
            im.save(location + 'test.png', 'PNG')
        except IOError:
            return


def main():
    handle = getWindowHandle("Blender")
    if not handle: return

    window = Window(handle)
    window.screenshot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The script gives me a black screenshot for some applications, such as Blender or DOSBox.

Does anyone know what causes this issue for only some applications and how I could fix it?

**EDIT**: It seems my problem might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899655/bitblt-ignores-captureblt-and-seems-to-always-capture-a-cached-copy-of-the-targe) post, although I am not sure what I'd have to do to fix my issue. I'd also like to add that I have also tried the adding CAPTUREBLT flag without any differences.

Comment: Try add CAPTUREBLT flag.

Comment: Are you using Windows Vista/7 with Aero enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> BitBlt returns an error if the source and destination device contexts represent different devices. To transfer data between DCs for different devices, convert the memory bitmap to a DIB by calling GetDIBits. To display the DIB to the second device, call SetDIBits or StretchDIBits.

What does this mean? In short, mixing DWM (i.e. Aero) and non-GDI applications (OpenGL, for example) makes BiBlt a unpredictable/unreliable.

Again from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The desktop composition feature, introduced in Windows Vista, fundamentally changed the way applications display pixels on the screen. When desktop composition is enabled, individual windows no longer draw directly to the screen or primary display device as they did in previous versions of Windows. Instead, their drawing is redirected to off-screen surfaces in video memory, which are then rendered into a desktop image and presented on the display.

Since blitting with the DWM has these [know issues](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/2007-06/msg00102.html), you may:

1. try to use alternative techniques; you have [a nice list here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/03/25/ways-to-capture-the-screen.aspx)
2. you may disable DWM (temporarly) using `DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION);`

Try and see if any works for you.

AFAIK however, the only way to reliably get the content of an application which uses 3D rendering (DirectX or OpenGL) is to  is to inject yourself into the process and copy out the bits (see [this answer for DirectX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1962286/863564), or hook `wglSwapBuffers` and do a readback with `glReadPixels` for OpenGL)

Comment: Hi, how can "to transfer data between DCs for different devices, convert the memory bitmap to a DIB by calling GetDIBits. To display the DIB to the second device, call SetDIBits or StretchDIBits.", this be implemented to take a screencapture of another window? I am searching for an API to get the contents of target window as a HBITMAP and then use GetDIBits() on that and read the pixel data, but none is working..