# How can I capture a transparent or translucent window in win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to have a transparent window which has only borders and than capture it (and see all the windows behind it - since its transparent) to bitmap.
I managed to create the transparent window but when I try to capture it than it ceases to be transparent and I get it original background.

This is what I have so far,

1. creating the window:

   ```
   //registering the window class with white backgournd
   WNDCLASSEX wcex;
   wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
   wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
   wcex.lpfnWndProc    = ScreenCaptureROIWinProc;
   wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
   wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
   wcex.hInstance      = _WPModule.GetHInstance();
   wcex.hIcon          = NULL;
   wcex.hCursor        = NULL;
   wcex.hbrBackground  = CreateSolidBrush(0x00FFFFFF);//white brush;
   wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
   wcex.lpszClassName  = g_lpszClassName;
   wcex.hIconSm        = NULL;

   RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

   //creating a layered window
   m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_LAYERED,g_lpszClassName, NULL,
                           WS_THICKFRAME, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL,
                           NULL, hInstance(), NULL);

   // Set white brushed sections of the window to be transparent
   SetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_hWnd, 0x00FFFFFF, 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
   ```
2. capturing the window:

   ```
   RECT ROIRect;
   GetWindowRect(m_hWnd,ROIRect);
   HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(m_hWnd);          
   HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);

   BitBlt(
   hdcMem,
   0,
   0,
   ROIRect.right - ROIRect.left, //width of window
   ROIRect.bottom - ROIRect.top, //height of window
   hdcScreen,
   0,
   0,
   SRCCOPY);
   ```

Comment: You need to include the CAPTUREBLT option in the last argument for BitBlt() to include layered windows.

Comment: I have tried it, setting just CAPTUREBLT in the last argument captured nothing, and setting (SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT) captured the original background.

Comment: Capture the whole screen and then clip to the boundaries of the target window?

Comment: This question deals with a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2899655/3826372

Comment: @Jonathan Tried that too (capturing the whole screen and then clipping the boundaries) but it didn't work as well. Also I want to support the window to be able to move between  multiple monitors and I think that capturing the whole screen may make it too complex. I changed the code above to `hdcSreen = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());`